# Create a Json Array without the Json Array name

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, gson

I'm having problems creating a Json output in an array without the array name. Currently when I create one I get the following Json response.

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "item1": "",
      "item2": "",
      "item3": "",
      "item4": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to remove following:

```
{
  "values": [
  ]
}
```

And have the end result look like the following:

```
[
   {
      "item1": "",
      "item2": "",
      "item3": "",
      "item4": ""
   },
   {
      "item1": "",
      "item2": "",
      "item3": "",
      "item4": ""
   }
]
```

Here is my code I'm currently using.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(new File(getFileName(base64), MimeTypes.ContentType(FileExtension.getType(base64)), folder, convertUriToBase64(), null));

Log.d(TAG, JsonUtil.toJson(jsonArray));
```

And here is my model class:

```
public class File {

    String fileName;
    int fileType;
    String fileFolder;
    String base64String;
    byte[] bytes;

    public File(String fileName, int fileType, String fileFolder, String base64String, byte[] bytes){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.fileFolder = fileFolder;
        this.base64String = base64String;
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
}
```

Any help will be useful thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `jsonArray.toString()`?

Comment: @digitalbreed Yes and it doesn't return a valid json instead it returns a `["com.package.name.File@d917cac"]`

Comment: Well, you put a `File` into it, which is not a valid `JsonElement`.

Comment: @digitalbreed 'File' is a custom model class.

Comment: @digitalbreed I updated the question so you know what I mean

Comment: What I am trying to say is: you can either use your own model classes and pass them into `Gson.toJson`, or you can use gson's abstraction of JSON elements. But you can't mix both and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix JSON elements with your own model. Here's an example using `Gson.toJson` which produces the expected result:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonTest {

    // Your model class
    public static class Test {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public Test(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Test(1, 2));
        list.add(new Test(2, 3));
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));

        // output: [{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":2,"y":3}]

    }

}
```

Comment: it works perfectly thank you, if I may ask how would one go about get lets say 2-10 items in a list. Like for example when you create a post on Facebook you can add a set amount of images to your post how would you go about getting all those images data and adding it an ArrayList?

Comment: @Tihan-NicoPaxton not sure what you mean with "getting all those images data", but if you are asking about building a similar process, with file selection, preview, cropping, uploading, storage, security,... that's probably a bit too much to answer in a single SO question.

Comment: Let's say you wanna post multiple images and upload it to a storage service, how would you go about it getting all those images data and adding it into the Json Arraylist. For example: 'List<Post> posts = new ArrayList(); posts.add(new Post("data"));' but instead of adding add whole time how would you get all them combined and add it as one, if that makes sense?